# How do I delete purgeable space detected by Disk Utility?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, mojave, spaces

I am French so I apologize in advance for any possible language errors. I'm running macOS Mojave (version 10.14.2).

Recently, I tried to run Bootcamp because I would like to install Windows. I went through the deletion of many files I didn't need to obtain more than 64 gigs of free space on the disk.

However, now that I would normally have the space to install Windows, Bootcamp tells me that there's not enough space on my disk because "The disk must have at least 40 GB of free space." I've checked Disk Dtility and it shows me there's 95,05 gigs that are purgeable. How to purge them?

I've searched for answers everywhere but it couldn't help me. It appears that the free space detected by the Disk Utility is different from the one shown by the global storage viewer. Pic related :

[image: It appears that the free space detected by the Disk Utility is different from the one shown by the global storage viewer]

driveinfo free space analysis
[image: drive info free space analysis]

I've also used "diskutil verifyVolume disk1" in terminal :
[image: diskutil verifyVolume disk1 -part 1]
[image: diskutil verifyVolume disk1 -part 2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clear the purgeable area on my disk?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254676/how-do-i-clear-the-purgeable-area-on-my-disk)

Comment: I've tried all of the above answers and it couldn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Traderhut Games](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/168111/traderhut-games)' answer from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252217/what-does-purgeable-means-in-storage-under-about-this-mac-section):

In Terminal, run

```
df -h /

Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused       ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1   466Gi  370Gi   64Gi    86%    xxxxx   xxxxxxxxx    0%        /
```

then, **for the disk you wish to use**, run:

```
diskutil secureErase freespace 0 /dev/disk1s1
```

Comment: I get "Erasing freespace only works on mounted and writable volumes"

Comment: Or if I try an identifier below the one showing in the `df -h /` command, I get "Error with secure disk erase: Secure erase by writing a run of bytes to an APFS Volume makes no sense due to its possibly-unbounded size (-69489)"

Answer (score -1):

I have used a combination of DaisyDisk and Cocktail (Onyx might do this as well, but I'm not familiar with that) Cocktail can delete local snapshots, which I think is what you are seeing. The Apple forums also has a Unix bases way of doing this, but as I am not completely comfortable with command line stuff, I let that go...

Hope this helps