# Time machine backup taking more space than expected

Tags: finder, backup, time-machine

I ran a storage check over my external hard drive (using omnidisksweeper) and found this:
[image]

While under the storage section of "About This Mac", I found this:
[image]

Which is accurate? If the omnidisksweeper is accurate, why is it that Mac says that there is free space of 600GB? I am quite confused and I am doing this check because I want to clear some of the old time machine backups (such as 2016-06-15) and not sure what are the files that consumed the most storage (and trying to delete them).

Pls advise! My end goal is to delete some large spaces files (so I was trying to inspect them with Get Info but it took too long time so ended up using omnidisksweeper)!

**Second Question >>**
Also, is it safe to just delete the files in Finder (aka command+delete in Finder)? Will it affect Mac's future backup restoration?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd attribute the ~200 GB difference to the 74.8 + 75.1 + 47.9 GB which somehow shows up on your app, but can be [purged when demanded](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252217/what-does-purgeable-means-in-storage-under-about-this-mac-section). No expert on DiskUsage here, nor did I comment on "deleting" them.

Comment: I would not delete anything.  When you need backup, you need backup. Time machine uses Unix links to keep track of things. The counting app you used got confused, I'd guess.

Comment: Additionally - Time Machine is designed to fill the volume over time, to maintain as long a history as it can, after which it recycles the oldest data. If you want it to use less space, put it on a smaller volume.

Comment: TM use 'directory hardlink'. omnidisksweeper might or might not recognize size correctly (counting some file repeatedly).